# computedStyle for -webkit-column-count

Tags: javascript

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(div, null).webkitColumnCount
```

this JavaScript gives me the correct column count when explicitly stating it in my CSS, but if I don't state the count in CSS - this property will return 'auto'.

I am wondering if there is anyway of returning the number of columns, even though the -webkit-column-count is in 'auto' mode. (as these columns still technically exist).